# Java program to compute the value of (2^n); the program should run with Big-O(2^n)

Tags: java, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

Is this java program runs with Big-O(2^n)? if not, any suggestions on how to modify it?

This program calculates the value of 2^n:

```
public static int exponent(int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;   
    else
        return 2 * exponent(n - 1);
}
```

Comment: This question looks an awful lot like you are trying to do homework and don't understand the basic concepts of Big-O to answer your own questions. While StackOverflow is intended for programming questions, there is the expectation that people asking questions do some research of their own before asking questions. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm flagging to close as Too Broad.

Comment: I am new to this website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news: it runs in `O(n)`.

Each iteration, `n` is decremented by `1`, so it loops exactly `n` times

Comment: Thank you Jean, any suggestion(s) on how to modify it to run Big-O(2^n) instead.

Comment: @Mike It *is* in O(2^n). If an algorithm is in O(n), it is always in O(2^n), too.

Comment: Great!! Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is even in O(n) and therefore also in O(2^n).

Comment: So, let say n = 3; if Big-O(n) then it runs 3 times, but if Big-O(2^n), it runs 8 times instead right? plz correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: @Mike No, Big-O notation is much more complex than that. Look it up at the Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: @Mike: First of all, it just gives an *upper* bound, which is the reason, why the implication in  my answer works. Second of all, you are allowed to apply a multiplicative constant. Thirdly, your algorithm must only respect that bound for problems bigger than a minimum size.

Comment: Great!! Thanks a lot for your clarifications

Answer (score 2):

To have a big-O which is proportional to the solution it should reduce to 1 i.e. it should make as many calls as the answer.

For there to be O(2^n) time complexity

```
public static int power(int base, int n) {
    return n == 0 ? 1 : multiply(base, power(base, n -1);
}

public static int multiply(int a, int b) {
    return a > 0 ? add(multiply(a - 1, b), b) : 0;
}

public static int add(int a, int b) {
    return a > b ? 1 + add(a -1, b) : b > 0 ? 1 + add(0, b -1) : 0;
}
```

To calculate 2^n it will reduce down to `1 +` 2^n times.

Comment: :) there is an easier way though, just use  return exponent(n - 1) + exponent(n - 1); instead of return 2 * exponent(n - 1); in code in question.

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm has `O(n)` time complexity. If you add a second parameter, you can make a method with `O(log n)` time complexity.

```
public static int power(int base, int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (n % 2 == 0)
        return power(base * base, n/2);
    else
        return base * power(base * base, n/2);
}
```

In your code, `n` is reduced by `1` every time, so it takes `n` steps to terminate. With this approach, `n` is halved every time, so it can finish much more quickly.